# Why eslint throw error when I want check array length?

Tags: eslint

why eslint throw error ( no-unused-expression ). I simply want to check if array is empty or not, and execute dispatch.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    cart.length
      ? cart.forEach((item: AsideItemInterface) => {
        totalPrice += item.quantity * item.price;
        dispatch(setTotal(totalPrice));
      })
      : dispatch(setTotal(0));
  }, [cart]);
```

If, I remove eslint-disable-next-line, get error.

Comment: is the value of cart async? try  `cart?.length`

Comment: What is the error? Also where is cart defined? What is cart initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're writing an expression that has a value result, but you're not using that result. More specifically, you're using the `? :` operators like an `if` statement. The solution is to write the `if` statement that you're actually using (i.e `if (cart.length) { ... } else { ... }`).